# Why are my styles not being updated in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a Sign In button that has an opacity of 50% normally but when you enter text in both the username and password or you click the Sign In button it is supposed to have an opacity of 100% (no transparency left at all).  However, when the button is clicked it changes the background color but the opacity remains at 50%.  Does anyone know why the opacity is not getting updated?

```
let readyForSignIn = this.state.email && this.state.password ? true : false;
let updateButton = this.state.loggingIn || readyForSignIn;

<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, updateButton ? styles.buttonActive : styles.buttonDefault]} onPress={() => this.onSubmitEmail()}>
    {this.state.loggingIn ? 
        <Text style={[styles.buttonText, {color: '#000'}]}>
            Signing you in...
        </Text>
    :
        <Text style={[styles.buttonText, {color: '#fff'}]}>
            Sign In
        </Text>
    }
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and here are the styles for the button:

```
buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#3A3A3A',
    paddingVertical: 16,
    borderRadius: 3,
    shadowOpacity: 0.35,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {widget: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 2
},
buttonDefault: {
    opacity: 0.5
},
buttonActive: {
    backgroundColor: '#fce443',
    opacity: 1
},
```

I made a video of the issue as well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp1fXVyHxoY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inline-style does not guarantee the order in which styles are applied** (e.g. can be alphabetically order). So you should use the most specific style names you can.

For background opacity, use this instead:

```
buttonDefault: {
    backgroundColor: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.5);
},
buttonActive: {
    backgroundColor: rgba(252, 228, 67, 1);
},
```

Comment: For react native I had to put the rgba color codes in quotes but other than that it worked perfectly!!  thx